# Is it possible to connect to an i2c device through a USB to RS485 serial converter cable on Linux?

Tags: linux, i2c, usbserial, ftdi, d2xx

I currently have a sensor attached to a USB to RS485 Serial converter cable which is plugged in to a raspberry pi. I've tried using the ftdi d2xx drivers to connect to it, but so far I can't read any data and while the writes don't fail, I'm not sure they're working.

This setup works on Windows with the custom software provided by the manufacturer, but I can't find anything on getting it to work on a linux system. Is this possible?

Comment: Questions related to Raspberry Pi are best asked on [rasberrypi.stackexchange.com](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: `minicom` might do it..

Comment: Raspberry Pis have i2c interfaces already. No need for USB or RS485.

Comment: Where you get the USD-to-RS485 convertor? Any model number or photo, post it if any, to find out the chip model in order to get the right driver?